# How to send and receive data using JavaScript Fetch

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am trying to make a request to an external page in JS and return the data. This will need to await a response so using AJAX I dont think will work but I may be mistaken. I am not well versed in JS so forgive me if im way off here just trying to learn.

Here is the request script -

```
fetch('return.php', { 
    method: 'GET'
 })
 .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
 .then(function(json) {
     obj = JSON.parse(text);
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + 
     obj.employees[1].lastName;
 });
```

Then I have a JSON response in the return file -

```
var text = '{"employees":[' +
    '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
    '{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
    '{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';
```

Everytime I try and execute this I get

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Which I believe means it is not returning JSON data but I may be wrong. How can I make a request to the return page and return data when its finished with the function execution.

Thanks!

Comment: It'd make sense to check the response and see what's in it, e.g., a CORS error, an access error, etc.

Comment: the response of fetch is already a JSON, then why are you parsing it again to JSON. if you pass a JSON to JSON.parse it will through an error

Comment: DO NOT build JSON manually.

Comment: If I remove the JSON parse I still get the same error

Comment: Also, what is `text`? `text` does not have anything to do with the `fetch`.

Comment: Because Text is the variable name of the array but yeah maybe I dont need that?

Comment: You don't have a "JSON response in the return file"; you have some JavaScript code. JS code in a PHP file won't be executed as JS, it'll be executed as PHP, which JS is not. If you want to return JSON from a PHP endpoint then it'd make sense to do that using whatever mechanism your PHP setup is using.

Answer (score 0):

`Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`
strongly implies that return.php is returning html of some kind. Try navigating to return.php to see what it's returning, and then parse accordingly.

You do not need `obj = JSON.parse(text);`. This will throw an error as text is not defined, but your fetch call is failing on response.json(), as the response is not json.

Comment: Ok Thank you, the return.php only contains the obj variable as shown. There isn't anything else in the file. This is a test env. I setup to learn how to do this correctly

Comment: Your response isn't valid json - it's javascript. JSON is a format for data that is based off of javascripts format for objects, but it is NOT javascript.

I strongly suggest reading up on JSON here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: Ah Ok yeah I see what youre saying. The purpose of this will need to be in a JS file so should I not be using JS or is there a way to format the JSON so it can be returned. Sorry for my ignorance but im used to PHP which is really easy to send and receive data lol

Comment: @RyanD I'm confused. You said the server side is PHP; that's what's returning the response. It's currently returning HTML, which means the issue is on the PHP side. So should be really easy then.

Comment: There is no PHP, these are 2 files. send.js and return.js. I am trying to make a request in send.js and await a response in return.js

Comment: @RyanD It says `fetch(`return.php')`; that implies PHP. What are you making this request *to*?

Comment: @davenewton right now its just between the 2 files, send and return

Comment: @RyanD I don't understand what that means. Are you attempting to `fetch` a local file? What is the name of that file? If you expect JSON to be returned, then the file should contain JSON, not code that attempts to create JSON, and you'll need to work around local file `fetch` limitations. I'm finding it difficult to understand what you're actually asking; you may want to edit the question and provide meaningful details.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry I was on my phone and hard to comment.. So I have 2 files on my server, send.php and return.php. Both files are just for testing sending and receiving data in JS. In send.php I am trying to make a request to return.php. Return.php is just a simple JSON response that I am trying to retrieve. The JSON response in return.php has to be in JS for my application otherwise I would just use PHP. The purpose is to be able to make a JS request and await the response without any re-directs or reloading the send.php page. Again I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: The purpose of this is to send a transaction on the TRON network which needs an await method to wait for the response otherwise I would just use ajax, maybe I still can but my understanding is you cannot use async in this way since the return data isnt available at the instant the function is executed

Comment: When I execute the transaction it returns a transaction id which is what I am trying to return to send.php to show if the transaction was successful. The goal is to not reload the page or redirect. Currently I can send the TX but I have to use window.location.replace("somepage.php?txid=..."); to get the transaction ID

Comment: @RyanD ... "The JSON response in `return.php` has to be in JS" doesn't make a lot of sense. It's either PHP, or JS, or JSON. If your server side is running PHP then it kind of has to be PHP--that PHP can *return* JSON, but you can't magically execute JS in a PHP file. "Just use Ajax..." `fetch` *is* Ajax. `await` is an *alternative* to using `then`. You might want to take a step back and edit the question with details--it's still not at all clear what you're trying to do, or that you understand what you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this fixes things? :

```
fetch('return.php', {
  method: 'GET',
})
  .then((response) => {
    response.json();
  })
  .then((jsonResponse) => {
    const obj = jsonResponse;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =
      obj.employees[1].firstName + ' ' + obj.employees[1].lastName;
  });
```

Comment: Yes I no longer get the JSON error now I get Cannot read property 'employees' of undefined. I will look into that

Comment: ok, then the problem is with the server side... i've read in the other comments... that there is no php? only two js files? do you have a server, made in express/node... to make the get request to? to send back the JSON?

Comment: Ok yeah this is the part im not familiar with. I can have 2 php files as they are on a server. I usually use PHP but I have to make a request in javascript so I am trying to return the response. It migh help if I explained why I guess.

Comment: Im playing with making transactions in TronWeb which the request is made in JS, so I need to return the data showing weather the transaction was successfull or not. Since I cant pass the JS to PHP I dont know how else to do it.

Comment: I tried AJAX but async wont work as I need to await the response